# Can I predict to have query performance problems against a two column xref table with 25 million records?

Tags: performance, database, oracle-11g

I'm prototyping a design.  In the design, I am considering creating a thin xref table (two integer fields) that would contain approximately 25 million records.  Is this a crazy idea or would I still expect decent performance?  By decent performance, I expect to query against this in a second or two.  I plan to index the first column.

I'm on Oracle.  I know this is a bit subjective as far as how the DB is tuned out, but let's assume I'm not doing anything too elaborate on the Oracle configuration side.  Just a ballpark - what kind of damage am I looking at?

I welcome ideas for breaking down an xref table if my approach seems ridiculous.

Comment: It's purely subjective, yes, but assuming 8 bytes per field, that's 382MB in total, right? I don't see a problem at all with performance.

Comment: @Randolph - Good point.  I've done some simple benchmarks and have good performance.  If you put your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's purely subjective, yes, but assuming 8 bytes per field, that's 382MB in total, right? I don't see a problem at all with performance.

(Repost from comment)